# Firefox 49 SecurityError - jquery.activity-indicator-1.0.0.min.js

Tags: jquery, firefox, runtime-error

since the upgrade to firefox 49 I seem to be getting this SecurityError: The operation is insecure. Using firebug I see it is coming from the jquery.activity-indicator-1.0.0.min.js file.

Any ideas/help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use development version of this library, find line 150

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(rule, 0);
```

and change it to

```
$('style').append(rule);
```

This is ugly hotfix, but it works for me.